# Removing newline character in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a text in a textarea and get the value using the .val() attribute. I would like to remove the linebreaks (which is the doublespace)?

i tried using the .replace

```
sampleText = sampleText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

But it did not give me the correct solution.

sample text from my textarea
[image]

when i tried the `.replace()`, it will do like this

[image]

how do i remove the space between sample 2 and sample 3? it should look like this..
[image]

Comment: `sampleText.split(/\r?\n/).filter(String).join("\n")`

Comment: You could simplify the regex to `sampleText.replace(/[\n\r]{2,}/gm, '\n')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split by new line, filter out an empty line and finally join

```
sampleText = sampleText.split(/\n|\r/).filter(function(value){
  return value.trim().length > 0;
}).join("\n");
```

**Example**

```js
var sampleText = "Sample 1\nSample 2\n\nSample 3";
sampleText = sampleText.split("\n").filter(function(value){
      return value.trim().length > 0;
    }).join("\n");
document.write('<pre>'+sampleText+'</pre>');
```

Comment: what about `\r`? what about `\r\n`? You need to account for differences in OS.

Comment: `/\r?\n/` is the right combo to hit them all, but chome on windows uses only "\n" in textareas if you use only the keyboard.

Comment: very nice. i never thought of that. Thanks so much.

Comment: @litlitDM `"Sample1\nSample2\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nSample3".split(/\n{2,}/gm).join('\n')` try this one liner.

Answer (score 2):

You need to double up on your by using the + sign on your group filtering to only include the double occurences, and don't replace them with an empty string but with a new newline.
For more information about the plus sign I recommend to read http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

This way every double occurence will be replaced by a single occurence, which is what you want I guess

```js
var sampleText = "Sample1\n\nSample2\n\r\n\r\r\r\nSample3";
document.write('<pre>Before:\n'+sampleText);


// The plus makes sure the matched pattern is repetitive and keeps replacing the doubles
sampleText = sampleText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)+/gm,"\r\n");

document.write('\n\nAfter:\n'+sampleText+'</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks.! but this only does the single break.. and not if multiple breaks. like 2 or more breaks..

Answer (score 0):

You can do the replacement of two line breaks:

```js
var sampleText = "Sample1\nSample2\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nSample3";
sampleText = sampleText.replace(/(\n){2,}/gm, "\n"); // matches 2 linebreaks to infinity;

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = sampleText;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Or just with `.join()` while creating an array out of string with `.split()`:

```js
var sampleText = "Sample1\nSample2\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nSample3".split(/\n{2,}/gm).join('\n')

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = sampleText;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```